# How to average time intervals?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, ora-00932

In Oracle 10g I have a table that holds timestamps showing how long certain operations took. It has two timestamp fields: starttime and endtime. I want to find averages of the durations given by these timestamps.  I try:

```
select avg(endtime-starttime) from timings;
```

But get:

> SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent
>   datatypes: expected NUMBER got
>   INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

This works:

```
select
     avg(extract( second from  endtime - starttime) +
        extract ( minute from  endtime - starttime) * 60 +
        extract ( hour   from  endtime - starttime) * 3600) from timings;
```

But is really slow.

Any better way to turn intervals into numbers of seconds, or some other way do this?

EDIT:
 What was really slowing this down was the fact that I had some endtime's before the starttime's. For some reason that made this calculation incredibly slow.  My underlying problem was solved by eliminating them from the query set.  I also just defined a function to do this conversion easier:

```
FUNCTION fn_interval_to_sec ( i IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND )
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  numSecs NUMBER;
BEGIN
  numSecs := ((extract(day from i) * 24
         + extract(hour from i) )*60
         + extract(minute from i) )*60
         + extract(second from i);
  RETURN numSecs;
END;
```

Answer (score 27):

There is a shorter, faster and nicer way to get DATETIME difference in seconds in Oracle than that hairy formula with multiple extracts.

Just try this to get response time in seconds:

```
(sysdate + (endtime - starttime)*24*60*60 - sysdate)
```

It also preserves fractional part of seconds when subtracting TIMESTAMPs.

See http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2009/04/converting-oracle-interval-data-type-to.html for some details.

---

Note that [custom pl/sql functions have significant performace overhead](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:60122715103602) that may be not suitable for heavy queries.

Comment: seems like the simplest solution so far. Would be good if Oracle could create a normal function for that.

Comment: This will multiple the interval difference by `24*60*60 = 86400` and then add it to the date which will give the result as a date and lose any fractional seconds - so if the timestamps are accurate to a microsecond (or anything smaller than 1/86400 seconds) then it will lose accuracy.

Comment: @MT0, you are right. Nanosecond precision for [TIMESTAMP(9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987975/oracle-timestamp-data-type) can be achieved with `(sysdate + (end_ts - start_ts)*24*60*60*1000000 - sysdate)/1000000.0`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. To me this is very helpful.

Answer (score 10):

If your endtime and starttime aren't within a second of eachother, you can cast your timestamps as dates and do date arithmetic:

```
select avg(cast(endtime as date)-cast(starttime as date))*24*60*60 
  from timings;
```

Comment: This will lose any fractional seconds in the timestamps (regardless of whether they are within a second of each other).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there is any function to do an explicit conversion of `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` to `NUMBER` in Oracle.  See the table at the end of [this document](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm#i46862) which implies there is no such conversion.

Other sources seem to indicate that the method you're using is the only way to get a number from the `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` datatype.

The only other thing you could try in this particular case would be to convert to  number before subtracting them, but since that'll do twice as many `extract`ions, it will likely be even slower:

```
select
     avg(
       (extract( second from endtime)  +
        extract ( minute from endtime) * 60 +
        extract ( hour   from  endtime ) * 3600) - 
       (extract( second from starttime)  +
        extract ( minute from starttime) * 60 +
        extract ( hour   from  starttime ) * 3600)
      ) from timings;
```

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a681f/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

Create a type to use when performing a custom aggregation:

```
CREATE TYPE IntervalAverageType AS OBJECT(
  total INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(9),
  ct    INTEGER,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT IntervalAverageType
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAverageType,
    value       IN     INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAverageType,
    returnValue    OUT INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAverageType,
    ctx         IN OUT IntervalAverageType
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY IntervalAverageType
IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT IntervalAverageType
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := IntervalAverageType( INTERVAL '0' DAY, 0 );
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAverageType,
    value       IN     INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF value IS NOT NULL THEN
      self.total := self.total + value;
      self.ct    := self.ct + 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAverageType,
    returnValue    OUT INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF self.ct = 0 THEN
      returnValue := NULL;
    ELSE
      returnValue := self.total / self.ct;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAverageType,
    ctx         IN OUT IntervalAverageType
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    self.total := self.total + ctx.total;
    self.ct    := self.ct + ctx.ct;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then you can create a custom aggregation function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION AVERAGE( difference INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND )
RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING IntervalAverageType;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH INTERVALS( diff ) AS (
  SELECT INTERVAL '0' DAY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '-1' DAY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '8' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL FROM DUAL
)
SELECT AVERAGE( diff ) FROM intervals
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a681f/2/0)**:

```
| AVERAGE(DIFF) |
|---------------|
|     0 2:0:0.0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a really quick and dirty method, but what about storing the seconds difference in a separate column (you'll need to use a trigger or manually update this if the record changes) and averaging over that column?

Comment: If you want to do this you can use a function based index (fbi) that saves you a trigger or manual update of a column. A fbi can be used in the where-clause but also in the select-clause.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Oracle does not support most functions with intervals.  There are a number of workarounds for this, but they all have some kind of drawback (and notably, none are ANSI-SQL compliant).

The best answer (as @justsalt later discovered) is to write a custom function to convert the intervals into numbers, average the numbers, then (optionally) convert back to intervals.  Oracle 12.1 and later support doing this using a `WITH` block to declare a function:

```sql
with
    function fn_interval_to_sec(i in dsinterval_unconstrained)
        return number is
    begin
        return ((extract(day from i) * 24
               + extract(hour from i) )*60
               + extract(minute from i) )*60
               + extract(second from i);
    end;
select numtodsinterval(avg(fn_interval_to_sec(endtime-starttime)), 'SECOND') 
  from timings;
```

If you are on 11.2 or earlier, or if you prefer not to include functions in your SQL statements, you can declare it as a stored function:

```sql
create or replace function fn_interval_to_sec(i in dsinterval_unconstrained)
    return number is
begin
    return ((extract(day from i) * 24
           + extract(hour from i) )*60
           + extract(minute from i) )*60
           + extract(second from i);
end;
```

You can then use it in SQL as expected:

```sql
select numtodsinterval(avg(fn_interval_to_sec(endtime-starttime)), 'SECOND') 
  from timings;
```

#### Using `dsinterval_unconstrained`

Using the PL/SQL type alias `dsinterval_unconstrained` for the function parameter ensures you have maximum precision/scale; `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` defaults `DAY` precision to 2 digits (meaning anything at or over ±100 days is an overflow and throws an exception) and `SECOND` scale to 6 digits.

Additionally, Oracle 12.1 will raise a PL/SQL error if you try to specify any precision/scale in your parameter:

```sql
with
    function fn_interval_to_sec(i in interval day(9) to second(9))
        return number is
        ...
```

`ORA-06553: PLS-103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following: to`

### Alternatives

#### Custom aggregate function

Oracle supports custom aggregate functions written in PL/SQL, which would allow you to make minimal changes to the statement:

```sql
select ds_avg(endtime-starttime) from timings;
```

However, this approach has several major drawbacks:

- You have to create the [PL/SQL aggregate objects](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5269744394385) in your database, which may not be desired or allowed;
- You cannot name it `avg`, as Oracle will always use the builtin `avg` function rather than your own.  (Technically you can, but then you have to qualify it with schema, which defeats the purpose.)
- As @vadzim noted, aggregate PL/SQL functions have significant performance overhead.

#### Date arithmetic

If your values are not significantly far apart, @vadzim's approach works as well:

```sql
select avg((sysdate + (endtime-starttime)*24*60*60*1000000 - sysdate)/1000000.0) 
  from timings;
```

Be aware, though, that if the interval is too great, the `(endtime-starttime)*24*60*60*1000000` expression will overflow and throw `ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small`.  At this precision (1μs) the difference cannot be greater than or equal to `00:16:40` in magnitude, so it is safe for small intervals, but not all.

Finally, if you are comfortable losing all subsecond precision, you can cast the `TIMESTAMP` columns to `DATE`; subtracting a `DATE` from a `DATE` will return the number of days with second precision (credit to @jimmyorr):

```sql
select avg(cast(endtime as date)-cast(starttime as date))*24*60*60 
  from timings;
```