# Oracle SQL sum dsinterval

Tags: oracle

i have a query which gets a time difference from two timestamps, which basically looks like this

```
SELECT (time_a - time_b) FROM t_tabel WHERE t_some_id IN('1','2','3');
```

then I get the output

```
0 0:4:0.0
1 0:15:0.0
0 0:20:0.0

DAYS HOURS24H:MINUTES:SECONDS:MILLISECONDS
```

Now I just want to sum up these times, I've tried several things but nothing wont work.

```
SELECT sum(time_a - time_b) FROM t_tabel WHERE t_some_id IN('1','2','3');
```

gives me: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

```
SELECT sum(to_dsinterval(time_a - time_b)) FROM t_tabel
WHERE t_some_id IN('1','2','3');
```

gives me: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

```
SELECT sum(SELECT time_a - time_b FROM t_tabel
WHERE t_some_id IN('1','2','3')) from dual;
```

gives me: missing expression

```
SELECT sum(SELECT to_dsinterval(time_a - time_b) FROM t_tabel
WHERE t_some_id IN('1','2','3')) from dual;
```

gives me: missing expression

Somehow it's got to work.

Comment: Are all your fractional seconds values really zero? If so they could be stored as `DATE`, or could be cast to `DATE` to do the summation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to average time intervals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450581/how-to-average-time-intervals) (OK, that's for `AVG`, but the principal is the same for `SUM`, and it links to an AskTom article that tackles both...)

Comment: Well spotted! I guess one moral here is to use datatypes as accurate as your problem requires. In this case it seems that `date` would be more than fine and `timestamp` is overkill. On the other hand, there are cases when I would want to use `timestamp with timezone` because I want the timestamp handling even if I don't need the precision.

Comment: @Colin'tHart - indeed, but I've seen `TIMESTAMP` used because it isn't obvious (if coming from another DBMS maybe) that `DATE` can also store a time, particularly if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` doesn't show the time part.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Oracle supplies us with these wonderful interval datatypes but doesn't provide the aggregate functions needed to `sum` or `avg` them!

Luckily Tom Kyte has written the necessary functions to implement this, see http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5269744394385

I found this because I've used this in the past and found it again by Googling "oracle interval aggregation".

Comment: A good blog post on the same subject can be found at http://markhoxey.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/interval-aggregation/